# Blank Sudoers File

Tags: command-line, error, sudo

I have been trying to set up some stuff for JS, but I need to use sudo. Every time I use sudo, I get this message.

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 80 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 82 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 84 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 80
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I checked the `/etc/sudoers` file and found out that it is completely empty. How would I fix this?

Comment: Your first step would be to reinstall macOS without losing data. You can do this from macOS Recovery. Next, remember to always use ```sudo visudo``` to edit the shudders file so that you don't get errors with /etc/sudoers. If this works, let me know so that I can add it as the answer.

Comment: I really don't want to reinstall as that would probably take a long time and this is my Daily Driver.

Comment: This would probably be the best option rather than further tampering with your sudoers file. If you install overnight, you should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that Todd said that it wasn't smart to do this, but I went to the [opensource sudoers file from apple](https://opensource.apple.com/source/sudo/sudo-60/src/sudoers) and copied that into my sudoers file, now sudo is working just fine!

Comment: I would mark this as the answer but I have to wait 2 days.

Comment: It’s perfectly safe to do that; it’s the exact same file Apple uses.  `/etc/sudoers` is just a text file “describing” who gets elevated permissions.  +1 for finding a great solution.

Comment: How would this work in Catalina?

Comment: What did you do before you copied the file to make sure you have the right to write the file?

Comment: I looked at the get info page and added myself to the list of users who can read/write.

Answer (score 3):

1. Boot to recovery mode
2. Open Terminal (menubar > Utilities > Terminal)
3. cd to your system data volume:

   ```
   cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/private/etc/
   ```

   (In system 10.14 and lower this is /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/private/etc/)
4. Download a default macOS sudoers file (e.g. from an online repository)

   ```
   curl -LJO https://gist.githubusercontent.com/keith/9061156/raw/1f056fa364640900eb42fcc9023d60a759c668c8/sudoers
   ```
5. Check permissions:

   ```
   ls -l /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/private/etc/sudoers
   -r--r-----  1 root  wheel  1283 May 13  2020 /private/etc/sudoers
   ```
6. Boot to your main system volume
7. Edit the sudoers file with `sudo visudo` and replace it with the content of the default Catalina sudoers file:

   ```
   #
   # Sample /etc/sudoers file.
   #
   # This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
   #
   # See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.

   ##
   # Override built-in defaults
   ##
   Defaults    env_reset
   Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
   Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
   Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
   Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
   Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
   Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
   Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
   Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
   Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
   Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
   Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
   Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

   Defaults    lecture_file = "/etc/sudo_lecture"

   ##
   # User alias specification
   ##
   # User_Alias    FULLTIMERS = millert, mikef, dowdy

   ##
   # Runas alias specification
   ##
   # Runas_Alias   OP = root, operator

   ##
   # Host alias specification
   ##
   # Host_Alias    CUNETS = 128.138.0.0/255.255.0.0
   # Host_Alias    CSNETS = 128.138.243.0, 128.138.204.0/24, 128.138.242.0
   # Host_Alias    SERVERS = master, mail, www, ns
   # Host_Alias    CDROM = orion, perseus, hercules

   ##
   # Cmnd alias specification
   ##
   # Cmnd_Alias    PAGERS = /usr/bin/more, /usr/bin/pg, /usr/bin/less

   ##
   # User specification
   ##

   # root and users in group wheel can run anything on any machine as any user
   root        ALL = (ALL) ALL
   %admin      ALL = (ALL) ALL

   ## Read drop-in files from /private/etc/sudoers.d
   ## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
   #includedir /private/etc/sudoers.d
   ```

---

Hint:

You can access this question & answer in Recovery Mode with Safari and copy the curl command.

Comment: a very thorough answer!